# Comprobar si existe una palabra en un diccionario

Tags: python

Hace un tiempo pregunté sobre cómo almacenar diccionarios.
Tengo en un TXT diccionarios de este estilo:

```
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Andalucia":202,"Canarias":330}} 
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucia":82,"Canarias":37}} 
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucia":802,"Canarias":0.137}}
```

Y gracias a la ayuda del foro, conseguí este código:

```
import ast

datos = []
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        to_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        datos.append(to_dict)

for i in datos:
    print(i.get('Comunidades',{}).get('Andalucia',{}))
```

Porque yo lo que quería era tomar los valores de Andalucía. Lo que ocurre es que hay diccionarios en los que 'Andalucía' no existe, por lo que me genera error. Entonces pensé en añadir un `if`:

```
datos = []
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        to_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        datos.append(to_dict)

for i in datos:
    if 'Andalucia' in datos:  
        print(i.get('Comunidades',{}).get('Andalucía',{}))
```

Pero entonces me extrae una lista vacía, como que para ese `if Andalucia` nunca está. Supongo que igual es porque `Andalucia` es la clave de una clave (comunidades), ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el código

```
for i in datos:
    if 'Andalucia' in datos:  
        print(i.get('Comunidades',{}).get('Andalucía',{}))
```

hay varios problemas.

Primero, estas iterando sobre `datos` y dejando en la variable `i` un diccionario, pero luego preguntas si "Andalucia" está `datos`, no en `i`.

Si corregimos la pregunta y ponemos

```
if 'Andalucia' in i:
```

tampoco funciona, pues el diccionario `i` sólo contiene dos llaves: `País` y `Comunidades`, por lo que la condición nunca se cumplirá.

El operador `in` aplicado a diccionarios sólo busca entre las llaves, no entre los valores. El operador no busca recursivamente.

Si la condición se cumpliera, el `print` es mucho más simple

```
print(i['Comunidades']['Andalucía'])
```

ya que ambas llaves existen.

**Solución**

Usar `i` como nombre de variable es mala idea, pues sugiere que contiene un valor entero, no un diccionario. Usar un nombre significativo ayuda a la comprensión y depuración del código.

En este caso, en lugar de `i` pondre `pais`, ya que eso es lo que contiene: el diccionario de un país.

Entonces, reemplaza

```
for i in datos:
    if 'Andalucia' in datos:  
        print(i.get('Comunidades',{}).get('Andalucía',{}))
```

por

```
for pais in datos:
    if 'Andalucia' in pais['Comunidades']:
        print(pais['Comunidades']["Andalucia"])
```

**Demo**

data.txt

```
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Barcelona":202,"Canarias":330}} 
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucia":82,"Canarias":37}} 
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucia":802,"Canarias":0.137}}
```

produce:

```
82
802
```

Nota: pésima idea usar llaves con acentos ("País"). La tilde sobre la `i` es indistinguible. Peor aún es la inconsistencia: la llave "Andalucia" aparece sin acento. Te imaginaras la cantidad de errores que eso genera en una aplicación real.